Speed up subscription renewal doesn't work
When testing inapp-purchases/subscriptions there was a gap in documentation that is causing the app to ignore the StoreKit Configuration File.
I was testing my subscriptions with a test user, on Xcode 16.
Following the documentation, I use a StoreKit Configuration File. And I set the Monthly renewal rate to 30 seconds:

And despite that, my renewals occur every 3-4 minutes... I also tried to set Any Renewal to 30 and 10 and 2 seconds, and it doesn't help. Same problem btw with an Annual subscription.
Any idea what is wrong with it?
Edit: my reply bellow explains how to solve this issue.

ok, after a few hours of research I found the answer:
One need to add the StoreKit Configuration File in the Scheme (in Product/Scheme/Edit Scheme), like in the screenshot. Mine was absent. After fixing this everything works are intended with the faster renewals.

